# iis ,wordpress, PHP Fatal error: require_once()

Tags: wordpress, iis

I relogin onedrive , then I visit "127.0.0.1" , get the below error .

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(E:\onedrive\webhome\wwwroot\wp-load.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in E:\onedrive\webhome\wwwroot\wp-blog-header.php on line 13
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'E:\onedrive\webhome\wwwroot/wp-load.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\onedrive\webhome\wwwroot\wp-blog-header.php on line 13
```

win10, iis, wordpress , onedrive, php 7.4 .

"E:\onedrive\webhome" folder , IIS_IUSER , full control .

Comment: i reinstall wordpress , but get the same error .

Comment: In all your future development or deployment, please never use OneDrive to host any files. That's a product designed to be installed on Windows client editions, without any consideration to be compatible with any enterprise features like IIS. Moved your files to a local drive and such miserable errors will disappear.

Comment: Either wp-blog-header.php isn't available in your website's directory, or your website's directory isn't in the include path.  The include path can probably be updated in the settings somewhere, or you could provide the entire path to the wp-blog-header.php file in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the safety or validity of storing dev code on OneDrive, but for anyone that has a legit reason to read files from a OneDrive folder via PHP:

- For Windows/IIS, the IIS_IUSER group needs permission to the folder(s) and file(s) in question
- OneDrive doesn't keep the full set files synced to your hard drive unless you tell it to.

I ran into this while needing to process some files in a OneDrive folder. OneDrive keeps 'ghosts' of the files on your hard drive to conserve space. Once you double click to a file to open it, it is downloaded to your hard drive and PHP will be able to access the file.

I don't know why PHP's various file reading commands don't trigger the download of the file, but to work around this issue you can select all files in a folder, right click and choose "Always keep on this device". You can also right click a folder and choose "Always keep on this device".

Once the file(s) and/or folder(s) have been fully synced to your hard drive, PHP should be able to access them. However I did have go back into folder properties, security, advanced, check the box to 'replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object' and apply that to all the files. After the permissions were reapplied for the newly downloaded files, PHP was able to read the files.

Given the issues with permissions not being applied, this could make stored dev code on OneDrive problematic. But if you need onetime access to process some files, this will hopefully get anyone else up and running.